# Requirement to pass array various types to a rules engine on a microcontroller. Having problems with casting

Tags: c++, casting, arduino, microcontroller

Sorry I am new both to the community and c++, please be gentle.

To begin with, as this is to run on a microcontroller, memory and compiled code space are extremely valuable.

I have a requirement to take input from various sources and feed them into a central processing function. The rolled up parameters fed in are to be named, be of varying types and, allow for type checking, so they can be compared against criteria  unknown at compile time. I have borrowed bits of code from here and there and come up with the following.

```
template <typename T_ty> struct TypeInfo { static const char * name; };
template <typename T_ty> const char * TypeInfo<T_ty>::name = "unknown";

#define MAKE_TYPE_INFO( type )  template <> const char* TypeInfo<type>::name= #type;

// Type-specific implementations.
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( int );
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( float );
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( String );
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( char * );
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( bool );

class ParaBase
{
public:
  char*   _type ;
  char*   _name;
  void*   _child;

  const char* name()  { return _name; }

  ParaBase(){}

  ParaBase(const char* name, const char* type, const void * child )
    :
    _name( (char*) name ),
    _type( (char*) type ),
    _child( (void*) child ) {}


  template <class U>
  bool is()
  {
    return ( TypeInfo<U>::name == _type );
  }

};

template <class T>
class Para : public ParaBase
{

  T _value;

public:

    Para( const char* name,  const T value )
    :
     ParaBase( name,  TypeInfo<T>::name, this ),
     _value( value )
    {}

    Para( ParaBase& paraBase )
        :
        ParaBase( paraBase._name,  paraBase._type, this )
    {}


  operator T()  { return _value; }

  const T value() { return _value; }

    template <class U>
    U as()
    {
        return *( ( U *)  _value );
    }


};
```

To test it I do the following:-

```
ParaBase para[3];

para[0] = Para<char*>("Param-one", "Hi");
para[1] = Para<bool> ("Param-two", true);
para[2] = Para<float>("Param-three", 2.05);
```

I can feed **para** into a central function fine.

```
bool ok = para[1].is<bool>(); // is true
bool notok = para[1].is<char*>(); // is false
```

So type checking works, yeah!

```
Para<char*> testDownCast =  ( Para<char*>)  para[0] ;
char* orig = testDownCast.as<char*>();
```

Erm, not so good. Major fail here. My testDownCast pointer *(if I am using the correct term)* just contains junk. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks in advance for helping a novice.

Comment: You might want to read [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Welcome to [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). You need an array of *pointers* for your idea to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Still struggling to get my head around a working solution. Not sure if I am approaching the problem in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
ParaBase para[3];
para[0] = Para<char*>("Param-one", "Hi");
```

You assign Para object to ParaBase object. As ParaBase object is *base* object, it will not contain any information that is specific to *derived* object (Para). In this case,

```
 T _value;
```

from Para object is lost. Then you assign back ParaBase object to Para object:

```
Para<char*> testDownCast =  ( Para<char*>)  para[0] ;
```

It's correct, but para[0] object does not contain any information about _value, so it cannot be copied back to testDownCast.

To make your example work, you should change array of ParaBase

```
ParaBase para[3];
```

to array of ParaBase pointers

```
ParaBase* para[3];
Para<char*> realPara0("Param-one", "Hi");

para[0] = (ParaBase*)&realPara0; //Or use C++-style cast here
```

Of course in this case you will not have ParaBase objects, only pointers to them. But you can cast back to Para object. You have to adjust rest of your code of course.

By the way - it's not good low-footprint microcontroller code. For each tempate type you use, new code will be generated. Also copying objects each time will cause your stack to grow (not a problem *until* you have small objects). 'Classic' microcontroller implementation would rely on *union*, and maybe additional information about type passed through union.

I'm not telling not to use C++ in microcontrollers (I'm great fan of this!), but this should be done with awareness. Here is great article (two parts) of using C++ in embedded systems:
http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4438660/1/Modern-C--in-embedded-systems---Part-1--Myth-and-Reality

Comment: Thanks, going to try it out.